# What is the suggested order for the X-Men animated series?

Tags: suggested-order, x-men-evolution, x-men-the-animated-series

I would like to watch the X-Men animated series from beginning to end to get to know it better. I mean, there are several series out there, but I don't know which one starts it all to begin with.

It would be great if someone could help me with a list in order to start with.

Comment: You want to know about all X-men animated shows or just X-Men: The Animated Series from 90s? And what is the confusion ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma, oh honestly, I don't know the difference between "all X-men animated shows" or just "X-Men: The Animated Series from 90s". I mean, I watched all X-Men movies from X1, X2, X3 and the new ones. So I would like to watch the animated versions to see all characters at full strength.

Comment: I don't see "several" series, merely three: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_(disambiguation)

Comment: I tried answering it, let me know if you seeking something else or need more details.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Many people consider three to be "several"; see e.g. https://xkcd.com/1070/.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

X-Men are part of animated [shows from 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_in_television) but there are only three major X-men animated shows:

1. [X-Men (1992–1997)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_(TV_series)) ( aka **X-Men: The Animated Series**): This one was the first successful launch of X-Men in an animated medium and ran for 5 seasons and 76 episodes. The show also had [crossover episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_X-Men_(TV_series)_episodes#Crossovers) with [Spider-Man (1994 TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1994_TV_series)) and was quite successful commercially and also critically acclaimed.
2. [X-Men: Evolution (2000–2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Evolution): X-Men Evolution was pretty well received too, but they played with the age of characters a lot, and made most of them teenagers. It ran for 4 seasons with 52 episodes.
3. [Wolverine and the X-Men (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_and_the_X-Men_(TV_series)) This one ran for only one season with 26 episodes and ended with a big cliffhanger which was never resolved.

All three shows work individually and have no impact on each other, so you can watch any one of the three or even all three.

There was one failed attempt at an animated show called [X-Men: Pryde of the X-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Pryde_of_the_X-Men) but it never made it, and only a pilot episode was created, so you can safely avoid it. [The Marvel Super Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marvel_Super_Heroes) also has X-men in them but they never call them by that name, and their main leads are non X-men members.

For elaboration on other X-Men animated stuff and cameos [refer this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_in_television).

Comment: Thanks man, for the answer. Now I know where to start with. ;)

Comment: @LouisT my personal fav is X-Men: Evolution.

Comment: With regard to the X-Men, if you are trying to figure out what is 'canon' I would recommend the podcast Jay and Miles Xplain the Xmen. I say this because they don't line up with each other, the comics, or the movies.

Comment: I read the first show you mentioned and thought "wow, there was another show before the _the Animated Series_?" Nope. I'm just that old.